# Python while loop won't end

Tags: python

So I have a code that project the user's bill. I put it on a loop so that it keeps repeating itself until the user don't want to continue.

here is my code:

```
status = True

def kill() :
    confirm = input("Again? (Y/N) : ")
    if confirm == "n":
        status = False

while(status):
    plan_option = input("Which plan are using ? (a/b/c/d/e):   ").lower()
    if plan_option == "a" :
        print("Your current bill is : $90")
        kill() 
    else :
        data_amount = float(input("How much data have you used?          "))

print("===========================") 

def plan_b(x) :
    if x < 10 :
        print("Your current bill is : $60")
    elif x > 10 :
        total = 60 + x*10
        print("Your current bill is : $", total)

def plan_c(x) :
    if x < 5 :
        print("Your current bill is : $40")
    elif x > 5 :
        total = 40 + x*12
        print("Your current bill is : $", total)

def plan_d(x) :
    if x < 2 :
        print("Your current bill is : $30")
    elif x > 2 :
        total =  + x*15
        print("Your current bill is : $", total)

def plan_e(x) :
        total = x*18
        print("Your current bill is : $", total)


if plan_option == "b" :
    plan_b(data_amount)
elif plan_option == "c" :
    plan_c(data_amount)
elif plan_option == "d" :
    plan_d(data_amount)
elif plan_option == "e" :
    plan_e(data_amount)

kill()
```

So my questions are :

1. If I enter "n" when the code prompt me, the script won't stop and kept going back to plan_option.
2. even though the code stops (eventually), it kept prompting me **"Again? (Y/N) : "** before it kills itself.

Where did I do wrong?
Also, am I over-engineering here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Comment: Rather than use a global for `status`, it would be better if `kill()` returned a status value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare 'status' as a global variable inorder to update value to
`"status = False"`   in your kill method.

You can do 2 things here:
1. Declare status as global variable
2. Return "status" (which is a local variable) from kill method

*You can check the tutorials on how to use global variables. Am not going to provide you the code (for your own good ofcourse).*

Comment: Thanks! It stops now, but even though the loop stops, it promps **"Again? (Y/N) : "** one more time before it kills itself. Why is that?

Comment: @YukaLangbuana That wasn't your original question. Please keep your question focused on _a particular problem_.

Comment: @YukaLangbuana that could be because you are calling "kill" again in the last line

Answer (score 3):

```
def kill() :
    confirm = input("Again? (Y/N) : ")
    if confirm == "n":
        status = False
```

This creates a *local* variable named `status`, and sets that. The global variable of the same name is unaffected.

Add `global status` in the function so that it uses the global one instead:

```
def kill() :
    global status
    confirm = input("Again? (Y/N) : ")
    if confirm == "n":
        status = False
```

Comment: Thanks! It stops now, but even though the loop stops, it promps **"Again? (Y/N) : "** one more time before it kills itself. Why is that?

Comment: Because the last line of your program is to call `kill()` one more time.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use less complicated way:

try this model

```
===>here your function a()<===

def a():
    print("A plan in action")


while True:
    ===> your loop code <===


    your_input = input("> ")
    your_input = your_input.upper()


    if your_input == 'N':
        print("\n** You escaped! **\n")
        break
    elif your_input == "A":
        print("\n** Plan A lunched ! **\n")
        a()
        ===>you can use 'break' to stop the loop here <=== 
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Two revisions:

1. Use `global status` in `kill()`
2. If you are comparing `confirm == "n"`, then convert `n` to lower while taking input

Try this:

```
def kill() :
    confirm = input("Again? (Y/N) : ").lower()
    if confirm == "n":
        global status
        status = False
```